# Trying to shift the perspective of a cylinder object in three.js without actually moving it's position

Tags: three.js, 3d

I'm working on a project where I'm putting a `3d cylinder object` in front of a static 2d image on a `three.js` canvas, trying to make the cylinder look like its part of the photo.

In order for the 3d cylinder's perspective to match the photo behind it, it needs to be moved down the `y axis`. The problem is then it's moved out of the scene. I need a way to render the `3d cylinder` how it would look with a -y position, but not actually move down the scene.

See image for details: 
[image: image are from https://imgur.com/u0JwAmZ]

Comment: Maybe try to rotate the cylinder slightly around the x-axis, finding the desired angle that fits to the image?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Rotating the cylinder's x-axis to about 24 degrees gets me the desired transformation on the top of the cylinder, but gives too much of a rounded shape to the bottom instead of the natural the half crest shape I' m looking for. He's another screenshot to confirm what I mean. Any ideas? [link](https://imgur.com/a/fIZrWQY)

Comment: Tru to play with FOV of the camera.

Comment: Thank you, shrinking the FOV and increasing the camera Z value got me the results I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `x-axis rotation` to around 24 degrees, Lowering the `FOV` to around 10, and increasing the `camera.position.z` to about 35 got me the results I needed. Thank you @prisoner849